# Making page in Joomla 2.5 fetch data from a database and export to excel

Tags: joomla2.5

I developed an application in Joomla using extensions. I used fabrik for data entry, data fetching and CSV extraction. The problem is in fabrik, the data that I am getting is in CSV format not Excel format. And now my requirement is: I want to make a page completely on my own from scratch that fetches data from a database that has already been entered through fabrik and displayed on the page.

I have no no idea how to make my own page that connects to a database to fetch values. Do I need to create a module only with .php, .xml, and index.html files? Or do I need to create a controller also? Where should I save my files?

Please help me in knowing:

- What files I need to make.
- Where I should place these files.

For the content of files, I will check on internet.

One question is will I have to design complete model view controller just to fetch and export already saved data . I just want one link on my existing website that will export already saved data to excel.please help ..For php  i got much help by stack overflow but for joomla not much. Please

Comment: you need to create a joomla component to show the data from database 

if you are using joomla 2.5 see documentation here 
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5

for older version (1.5.x) read this  
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

Comment: @Anand: Thank u very much. There are so many files do i need to create all? I am already using fabrik to save and retrieve data. Now I want to write a module or watever on my own to fetch data from the same database and convert it into html table. Thats it but it seems big task.ultimately i want a page that displays data in table form. thank u very much u r a hope for me

Comment: @Anand : Dont answer as any how i managed to get data on front end . But only thing is i am getting just one element . i will make changes. thank u very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here it goes.

Check your requirement. I think you need to create a component and also you need to be familiar with PHP and SQL. But this you can learn as you proceed to write your component. A component is based on MVC design pattern. You can, however, write a simple enough component with just V and C.

To create a component use this:

http://cocoate.com/jdev/component/step-2

Install the below mentioned component and then modify the view per you requirement. You can learn all these in a day or two. After that, you would be ready to reuse the same code for your new component. 
http://cocoate.com/sites/cocoate.com/files/com_coco_real_estate-0.0.2.zip

Comment: Thanks all.. will go thru tutorials.joomla is nt so easy even if i have data stored in dbase just to display that i will have to work hard.Is there someway to convert sql data to excel format. tried almost all extensions. Thanks again